# Excepted value of maximum of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

> let $\mathit X\sim Geo(p) $ and $\mathit Y\sim Geo(3p)$ independent random  variables and $\mathit M=Max\{X,Y \} $.
>   Find $\Bbb E[ M ]$?

We know that $\Bbb E[ Y ]=\frac{1}{3p} $ and  $\Bbb E[ X ]=\frac{1}{p}$ , so we know for sure that $\Bbb E[ M ]\gt\frac{1}{p} $ since we are taking the maximum.
But how do we calculate the exact value?

Comment: Should I find the pmf or pdf of max(X,Y)?@wolfies

Comment: Suggest forget the expectation, and reduce your problem to finding first the pmf of max(X,Y). You can then turn your attention to finding the excepted value, or expected value, as the case may be

Comment: I am having some problems calculating the pmf of the maximum.@wolfies